# How do I run a program that I git cloned?

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, timeserieschart

I'm new to git. I just git cloned [this library](https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts) and am trying to run the code in [this folder](https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts/tree/master/src/website/packages/charts/examples/baselines). I know that it uses Javascript so I tried using `npm start` but it gave me a `npm ERR! missing script: start` error. How do I run it?

Comment: You've to follow the `Developing` section on the repo https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts#developing

Comment: It's not a program, it's a library. You can't run it.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't understand. Isn't that an example program? The `index.js` file in `baselines`?

Comment: I think the question is whether you're trying to make changes to the library or simply integrate the library into your project

Comment: A library is usually a set of functions that you can use within a program. It is not a  program itself, although that term is a bit loose

Comment: You should use the [Getting Started guide](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/guide/start) on their docs. You are meant to install the package via npm and not cloning it using git. You would only clone the repo if you intend on modifying their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Getting Started guide](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/guide/start) on their docs. You are meant to install the package via npm and not cloning it using git. You would only clone the repo if you intend on modifying their code.

> **2.1 How to Install**
>   This charts library is intended to be installed with npm and the built into your project with a tool like Webpack. It expects React to be present, as well as our TimeSeries abstraction library, pond.js. More on this below.
>
> To install: 
>   `npm install react-timeseries-charts pondjs --save`